# Parameter fitting with nls.lm and ode, ""Error in chol.default(object$hessian)

Tags: r, ode

I am trying to fit a set of parameters in a set of ODE models using ode function from deSolve package and nls.lm function from minpack.lm.

The data that I am fitting is in this file: S1LDPE
https://github.com/nhazimah/Work-Package-1.git

I have created a function (S1newmodel) which lists down 6 sets of outputs (derivatives of concentrations for C1 and C2 in 3 different systems: sys1, sys2, sys3):

```
S1newmodel<- function(t,c,parms){

with(as.list(c(c, parms)),{
  #c is concentration on plastic
  #r is derivatives of the concentration on plastic

  #Description of parameters
  #k1: Fast step forward rate constant (k1-Cw->C1)
  #k2: Fast step reverse rate constant (k2-C1->Cw)
  #k3: Slow step rate constant
  #f1: fraction of plastic (P1/PT) in outer compartment (rapid process)

  #List of parameters set by each set-up (constant)
  tp=0.3178/70   #total plastic concentration in system (kg/L)         
  m=0.0053773     #total micelle concentration in system (kg/L)
  #Kow: Kow of chemical                                      

  #Calculation of Km from Kow
  Km=10^(0.76*log10(Kow)+0.88)


  #Calculation of Cw from mass balance
  Cw1=(cinit["C11"]*tp-tp*(f1*c["C11"]+(1-f1)*c["C21"]))/(Km*m+1)
  Cw2=(cinit["C12"]*tp-tp*(f1*c["C12"]+(1-f1)*c["C22"]))/(Km*m+1)
  Cw3=(cinit["C13"]*tp-tp*(f1*c["C13"]+(1-f1)*c["C23"]))/(Km*m+1)

  #Calculation of k2 from K(polymer)
  #k2=k1/(K*f1*tp)

  #derivatives dc/dt are computed below
  r=rep(0,length(c))
  r[1]=(k1/(f1*tp))*Cw1-(k2+k3)*c["C11"]+k3*c["C21"]        #dC1/dt (in ug/kg of component 1)
  r[2]=k3*c["C11"]-k3*c["C21"]                                  #dC2/dt (in ug/kg of component 2)
  r[3]=(k1/(f1*tp))*Cw2-(k2+k3)*c["C12"]+k3*c["C22"]        #dC1/dt (in ug/kg of component 1)
  r[4]=k3*c["C12"]-k3*c["C22"]                                  #dC2/dt (in ug/kg of component 2)
  r[5]=(k1/(f1*tp))*Cw3-(k2+k3)*c["C13"]+k3*c["C23"]        #dC1/dt (in ug/kg of component 1)
  r[6]=k3*c["C13"]-k3*c["C23"]                                  #dC2/dt (in ug/kg of component 2)

  #k1 from steady state solution
  Kp=k1/(k2*f1*tp)

  #Kow and Kp relationship
  Kp=10^(a*(log10(Kow))+b)


  return(list(r))})

}
```

Next I created a function, ssq, which produces outputs of the residuals between prediction and actual data which will then be passed into nls.lm function to estimate the optimal parameters. However, unlike other previous existing examples for nls.lm, I am running a 'for' loop in the function to read different set of parameters to produce 5 sets of outputs of "out".

```
ssq=function(parms){

    for(i in 1:5){



  #time points for which conc is reported
  #include points where data is available  
  t=c(seq(0,672,0.5),S1LDPE$time[S1LDPE$system=="PCB18sys1"])                           
  t=sort(unique(t))

  #parameters from the parameter estimation routine

  a=parms[1]
  b=parms[2]
  k1=parms[i+2]
  k2=parms[i+7]
  k3=parms[i+12]
  f1=parms[i+17]
  Kow=Kow[i]

  cinit=c(C11=unname(parms[i+22]),C21=unname(parms[i+22]),
          C12=unname(parms[i+27]),C22=unname(parms[i+27]),
          C13=unname(parms[i+32]),C23=unname(parms[i+32]))


  #solve OD for a given set of parameters
  out[[i]]=ode(y=cinit,times=t,func=S1newmodel,parms=list(a=a,b=b,k1=k1,k2=k2,k3=k3,f1=f1,Kow=Kow))

  #Calculate Ctot dataframes (contain sys1, sys2, sys3) for each PCB
  Ctot1[[i]]=(out[[i]][,2]*parms[[i+17]])+(out[[i]][,3]*(1-parms[[i+17]]))
  Ctot2[[i]]=(out[[i]][,4]*parms[[i+17]])+(out[[i]][,5]*(1-parms[[i+17]]))
  Ctot3[[i]]=(out[[i]][,6]*parms[[i+17]])+(out[[i]][,7]*(1-parms[[i+17]]))
  Ctot[[i]]=cbind(Ctot1[[i]],Ctot2[[i]],Ctot3[[i]])

  }

  pred<-do.call(cbind,Ctot)
  preddf<-data.frame(pred)

  #Give names to dataframe with PCB#sys# format
  colnames(preddf)[1:3]=sprintf("PCB18sys%d",1:3)
  colnames(preddf)[4:6]=sprintf("PCB31sys%d",1:3)
  colnames(preddf)[7:9]=sprintf("PCB28sys%d",1:3)
  colnames(preddf)[10:12]=sprintf("PCB52sys%d",1:3)
  colnames(preddf)[13:15]=sprintf("PCB66sys%d",1:3)

  time=out[[1]][,1]
  preddf<-cbind(time,preddf)

  #filter data that contains time points where data is available
  preddf=preddf[preddf$time %in% S1LDPE$time[S1LDPE$system=="PCB18sys1"],] 

    #Evaluate predicted vs experimental residual
  preddf=melt(preddf,id.var="time",variable.name="system",value.name="conc")
  ssqres=preddf$conc-S1LDPE$conc      

  return(ssqres)
}
```

The following are the parameters and boundary conditions which I have guessed to be initial estimates (note: Kow is not a parameter. It is a fixed constant for each set):

```
#parameter fitting using levenberg marquart algorithm
#initial guess for parameters
k1<-c(10,10,10,15,20)
k2<-c(0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3)
k3<-c(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001)
f1<-c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
Cp1<-c(500,800,700,1000,1100)
Cp2<-c(600,800,700,1000,1000)
Cp3<-c(600,800,700,1000,1000)


parms  <- c(a=2,b=-1.5,k1=k1[1:5],k2=k2[1:5],k3=k3[1:5],f1=f1[1:5],Cp1=Cp1[1:5],Cp2=Cp2[1:5],Cp3=Cp3[1:5])

#Fixed values
Kow<-c(10^5.24,10^5.67,10^5.67,10^5.84,10^6.2)

#Frames for outputs
out<-c()
Ctot1<-c()
Ctot2<-c()
Ctot3<-c()
Ctot<-c()

#Lower and upper bounds
lower=as.vector(matrix(0,1,37))
lower[[2]]=-Inf

upper=as.vector(matrix(Inf,1,37))
upper[18:22]=1
```

Finally, I fit the above functions with nls.lm

```
#fitting
fitval=nls.lm(par=parms,fn=ssq,lower=lower,upper=upper)
```

The model seems to run but it stops at the i=2 and produces this message when I check summary:

Error in chol.default(object$hessian) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite